# can't see css with express.static()

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, express, sass

I'm trying to deploy areact-app using express server but I've got a problem while trying to link the front and the back. The jsx pages are working, but the style is not.
Here is my server.js document:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config/.env" });
require("./config/db");
const { checkUser, requireAuth } = require("./middleware/auth.middleware");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user.routes");
const messageRoutes = require("./routes/message.routes");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ["sessionId", "Content-Type"],
  exposedHeaders: ["sessionId"],
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  preflightContinue: false,
};
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
// jwt
app.get("*", checkUser);
app.get("/jwtid", requireAuth, (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(res.locals.user._id);
});
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/message", messageRoutes);
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/client/build/index.html"));
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

and here 's my file organisation

[image: and here 's my file organisation]

Comment: Have you tried `npm run build` and then the build folder to be the one that is served statically by node?

Comment: yes, that what I did and when I run "cd client", "cd build", "npm start", everything is working correctly. I can't serve the build folder statically cause there's a router (react-router-dom) inside this folder